# Defining a cell style of an attribute table in a layout using PyQGIS 3

Tags: attribute-table, style, print-composer, pyqgis-3

I have an attribute table in my layout, defined as follow :

```py
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().addLayout(layout)

pdf = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('plan_de_ferme')[0]
pdf_table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.create(layout)
pdf_table.setVectorLayer(pdf)
pdf_fields = ['champ','sup','supepnd']
pdf_table.setDisplayedFields(pdf_fields, True)
```

I would like to set a background color for the header row and all even rows, as follow :

[image]

I can use `pdf_table.setBackgroundColor(QColor(166, 206, 227, 255))`  to apply a blue color for the whole attribute table but it's not what I am looking for.

[image: attribute table 2]

I think I should use [QgsLayoutTable Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutTable.html#aa3f5027a3c9747f6c647cf264b43fd51a4d687869945ed82dfd3823a971333f85) and [QgsLayoutTableStyle Class](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Layout/QgsLayoutTableStyle.html). According to its [definition](https://qgis.org/api/qgslayouttable_8h_source.html#l00112), the class `QgsLayoutTable` has a method called `setCellStyle`  that requires two inputs :
`void setCellStyle( CellStyleGroup group, const QgsLayoutTableStyle &style )`

`CellStyleGroup` is a public type of `QgsLayoutTable`, defined ad follow in the [first link](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutTable.html#aa3f5027a3c9747f6c647cf264b43fd51a4d687869945ed82dfd3823a971333f85):
[image]

I don't know by what to replace "`const QgsLayoutTableStyle &style`"

I tried

```
pdf_table.setCellStyle(qgis.core.QgsLayoutTable.CellStyleGroup.EvenRows,
                        cellBackgroundColor(QColor( 166, 206, 227, 255 )))
```

but I get the following error: `"NameError: name 'cellBackgroundColor' is not defined"`,

and

```
pdf_table.setCellStyle(qgis.core.QgsLayoutTable.CellStyleGroup.EvenRows, 
                       QgsLayoutTableStyle().cellBackgroundColor(QColor( 166, 206, 227, 255 )))
```

but I get the error `"TypeError: 'QColor' object is not callable"`,

and

```
pdf_table.setCellStyle(qgis.core.QgsLayoutTable.CellStyleGroup.EvenRows, 
                       QgsLayoutTableStyle.cellBackgroundColor(QColor( 166, 206, 227, 255 )))
```

returns `"AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutTableStyle' object attribute 'cellBackgroundColor' is an instance attribute"`.

Like I'm not familiar with the several Python definitions, I don't understand what these means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the following short snippet of code to construct a `QgsLayoutTableStyle()` object, set its `enabled` and `cellBackgroundColor` attributes, and then pass it as the 2nd argument to the `setCellStyle()` method.

```py
table_style = QgsLayoutTableStyle()
table_style.enabled = True
table_style.cellBackgroundColor = QColor(166, 206, 227, 255)
pdf_table.setCellStyle(QgsLayoutTable.EvenRows, table_style)
layout.refresh()
```

Example result:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you !